# how do i properly access the coinbase advanced api

Tags: python, neural-network, traceback, coinbase-api

im trying to access the coinbase adveanced api ut im getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\user\coinbase_neural_network.py", line 47, in collect_data
candles = api.API.get_product_candles(product_id, start, end, granularity)
File "D:\user\Coinbase_neural_network\api.py", line 76, in get_product_candles
response.raise_for_status()
File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/products/LTC-USD/candles?start=01-01-2021&end=01-01-2022&granularity=ONE_HOUR

when i try to use the collect data function in this class:
import configparser
import http.client
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
from typing import Tuple, List, Dict, Any
import requests

```
class API:

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(r"D:\user\config.ini")
    api_key = config.get('coinbase', 'API_KEY')
secret_key = config.get('coinbase', 'SECRET_KEY')

@staticmethod
def generate_signature(timestamp: str, method: str, request_path: str, body: str) -> str:
    signature_string = timestamp + method.upper() + request_path + body
    hmac_object = hmac.new(API.secret_key.encode(), signature_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
    return hmac_object.hexdigest()

@staticmethod
def get_best_bid_ask() -> str:
    payload: str = ''
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    headers: dict[str, str] = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(timestamp, "GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/best_bid_ask", payload),
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    }
    with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
        conn.request("GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/best_bid_ask", payload, headers)
    res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
    data: bytes = res.read()
    return data.decode("utf-8")

@staticmethod
def get_brokerage_accounts(limit: int, cursor: str) -> str:
    payload: str = ''
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    headers: dict[str, str] = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(timestamp, "GET", f"/api/v3/brokerage/accounts?limit={limit}&cursor={cursor}", payload),
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    }
    with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
        conn.request("GET", f"/api/v3/brokerage/accounts?limit={limit}&cursor={cursor}", payload, headers)
    res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
    data: bytes = res.read()
    return data.decode("utf-8")

@staticmethod
def get_product_candles(product_id: str, start: str, end: str, granularity: str) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    payload: str = ''
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    headers: dict[str, str] = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(timestamp, "GET",
                                                 f"/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/candles", payload),
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp}

    start = start.replace(' ', 'T')
    end = end.replace(' ', 'T')
    url = f"https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/candles"
    params = {
        "start": start,
        "end": end,
        "granularity": granularity}
    print(timestamp)
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    candles = response.json()
    return [dict(zip(["start", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume"], c)) for c in candles]

@staticmethod
def get_market_trades(product_id: str, limit: int) -> Tuple[List[Dict[str, str]], str, str]:
    payload: str = ''
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    headers: dict[str, str] = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(timestamp, "GET", f"/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/ticker?limit={limit}", payload),
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    }
    with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
        conn.request("GET", f"/api/v3/brokerage/products/{product_id}/ticker?limit={limit}", payload, headers)
    res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
    data: bytes = res.read()
    trades: Dict[str, Any] = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    trade_data: List[Dict[str, str]] = [dict(zip(["trade_id", "product_id", "price", "size", "time", "side", "bid",
                                                  "ask"], t)) for t in trades["trades"]]
    best_bid: str = trades["best_bid"]
    best_ask: str = trades["best_ask"]
    return trade_data, best_bid, best_ask

@staticmethod
def create_buy_market_order(client_order_id: str, product_id: str, side: str, order_configuration: str) -> str:
    payload: str = json.dumps({
        "client_order_id": client_order_id,
        "product_id": product_id,
        "side": side,
        "order_configuration": order_configuration
    })
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    headers: dict[str, str] = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(timestamp, "POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders", payload),
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    }
    with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
        conn.request("POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders", payload, headers)
    res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
    data: bytes = res.read()
    return data.decode("utf-8")

@staticmethod
def create_sell_market_order(client_order_id: str, product_id: str, side: str, order_configuration: str) -> str:
    payload: str = json.dumps({
        "client_order_id": client_order_id,
        "product_id": product_id,
        "side": side,
        "order_configuration": order_configuration
    })
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    headers: dict[str, str] = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': API.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': API.generate_signature(timestamp, "POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders", payload),
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    }
    with http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com") as conn:
        conn.request("POST", "/api/v3/brokerage/orders", payload, headers)
    res: http.client.HTTPResponse = conn.getresponse()
    data: bytes = res.read()
    return data.decode("utf-8")
```

everything is passed right this is the timestamp: 1690483742
and url: Error occurred while collecting data: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/products/LTC-USD/candles?start=01-01-2021&end=01-01-2022&granularity=ONE_HOUR
am i entering the date wrong?`your text`

Comment: Yes, 1690483742 is the current time, but that's not what you're passing in your request for `start` and `end`.  You are supposed to send that large integer.  You need to translate your unusual MM-DD-YYYY format to a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the times as Unix timestamps.  So replace this:

```
    start = start.replace(' ', 'T')
    end = end.replace(' ', 'T')
```

With this:

```
    start = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%m-%d-%Y').timestamp())
    end = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%m-%d-%Y').timestamp())
```

That assumes (1) you have `import datetime` at the top, and (2) you always give your dates in MM-DD-YYYY format.

Comment: no i am still getting this traceback error: 
  line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/products/LTC-USD/candles?start=1609477200.0&end=1609477200.0&granularity=ONE_HOUR
Error occurred while collecting data: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/products/LTC-USD/candles?start=1609477200.0&end=1609477200.0&granularity=ONE_HOUR

Comment: And do you see anything in that URL that looks odd?  That's the key to debugging.  I see two things.  First, the fimestamps are floats.  Easily fixed.  Second, your start and end times are identical.  Only you can solve that.  We don't know what data you're feeding in.